# How does iterating through range(len(input_string)-1, -1, -1) give the reverse string?

Tags: python, string, for-loop, iteration

what does range(len(input_string)-1, -1, -1) do? why does it find the inverse of the string?

def string_reverse(input_string):
reverse_input = ''

```
    for i in range(len(input_string)-1, -1, -1): 
        reverse_input += input_string[i]
    
    return reverse_input
```

Comment: Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range

Answer (score 0):

In the loop you wrote, you move from a greater value that is `len(input_string)-1` to a smaller value -1(-1 is excluded so 0).

For ex. if length of string is 5, then in the first iteration the value of i is 4, then 3, 2, 1, 0. This is why this found the inverse of your string.

For any string, `input_string[len(input_string)-1]` will always be the last character of the string and `input_string[0]` will always be the first value in the string.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range this should help.